# Is Global location using OpenGL bound by the shader?

Tags: opengl, c++

I have recently started writing a game engine in C++ with OpenGL and using some tutorials online. So far from what I have seen, shaders are the way to manipulate an object's position in worldspace. Is this true or is there a way to write a physics engine which can work without shaders in order to "move" and object in worldspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaders are just programs that run on different stages of the graphics pipeline. You say:

> So far from what I have seen, shaders are the way to manipulate an
>   object's position in worldspace.

This is partially correct, as this is not the only thing shaders can do.
Moving an object's position in world space would be the job of a **vertex shader**.

Vertex shaders work on each vertex passed to it. A simple shader that moves an object would be like:

```
#version 410 core
uniform mat4 mvp;
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vPosition * mvp;
}
```

This shader simply does `for each vertex multiply by matrix mvp`.

The `mvp` is just a matrix comprised of a **Model Matrix**(the objects position), **View Matrix**(the view/"camera" matrix) and a **Projection Matrix**(usually a perspective projection martix).

There is a great OpenGL tutorial [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) which should help you further understand OpenGL, shaders and how matrices work to move your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Physics engine and shaders are unrelated. A game engine stores object's location/orientation somewhere and both shaders and physics engine can use it. Vertex shaders can modify the position to change an object's appearance but it's a visual thing, the rest of the game engine doesn't automatically get the modified position.